# Unable to follow release upgrade instructions to upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, updates, 19.04, 19.10

I am trying to upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 following [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes) instructions. When I come to `Select the 3rd Tab called 'Updates'`, I get the following message:

```
Unable to download updates:
failed to refresh cache: E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Start with http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: I see. Should I do a backup before upgrading or is it safe to say that my files will be preserved?

Comment: The answer to "should I do a backup" is pretty much always yes.

Comment: @pomsky yes it does